# jolokia: can't execute command with parameters

Tags: java, jmx, jolokia

Can't execute any command in jolokia, it always can't find signature. For example according to [documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html), this should work:

```
POST request

{
   "type":"EXEC",
   "mbean":"java.lang:type=Threading",
   "operation":"dumpAllThreads",
   "arguments":[true,true]
}
```

But I've got:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Operation dumpAllThreads on MBean java.lang:type=Threading is overloaded. Signatures found: (boolean,boolean),(boolean,boolean,int). Use a signature when specifying the operation
```

Any ideas? Java 11.0.6 2020-01-14 LTS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
POST request

{
   "type":"EXEC",
   "mbean":"java.lang:type=Threading",
   "operation":"dumpAllThreads(boolean,boolean)",
   "arguments":[true,true]
}
```